# Python: urllib2.urlopen retrns of type string

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to fetch a URL content by making a request first and then using urlopen function but when I tried to close the stream it gave me type error. Upon investigation I found it's returning string type. Below is my code:

```
 req = urllib2.Request(url, '', HEADERS)
 html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
 print(type(html)) #retrns str
```

I want to close urllib stram. How do I do it?

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen(...)` returns a stream. `html` is the result of calling `.read()` on that stream. You have to call `.close()` on that stream, not on `html`.

Comment: You're not closing the stream. You're closing a string. Try to store the result of `urlopen(...)` somewhere (perhaps in a variable called `stream`) before calling `.read()` on it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you make it as an Answer? Also I don't know why this question was downvoted. It's quite a valid question from a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing the stream. You're closing the string returned by `.read()`, and closing a string doesn't make sense.

Try to store the result of `urlopen(...)` somewhere (perhaps in a variable called stream) before calling `.read()` on it, so that you can also `.close()` it after you're done..